# How do I call previous fragments to a new fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

MainActivity > OneFragment > RadiolistFragment > newFragment

One Fragment contains tab layout(which contains names of the country) and radioListfragment contains a list of the fms based on the country..So what I need to do is call both OneFragment and RadioListFragment into newFragment..How can I achieve this?
[image: Nepali and Dominican are in OneFragment]

[image: All the fms are in RadioListFragment]

[image: What I need to do is Call both of the fragment here in the Squared area]

How can I do this?

Comment: post the code of changing the fragment.

Comment: I don't know how to do that..So,I need to know If i could do that or not..Can you please help?

Comment: have you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: I tried  passing data using bundles..But it sends null value..So i thought there might be a better way to call Fragment into another fragment...If there is a way..Please help me!

Comment: When you say "call fragment into another fragment" do you just mean you are trying to add a fragment to a framelayout?

Comment: Yeah..I need to show that view in that squared area..Did you see that images i posted above?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use container such as FrameLayout in your newFragment's xml :

- create 2 FrameLayouts set them as you want width and height etc, after that give them id for each example conainter1 and container2:
- Then you can create isntances of your fragments  :

  RadioListFragment rdLstFragment = new RadioListFragment();
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container1,rdLstFragment).commit();
  and the same for the other fragment in the container2.

or you can use fragment tag in xml and initialise directly you're fragments when your newFragment is created .
NB : i didn't right the code in IDE so you can find a spelling error in the methods names

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: I can give you access to github if you want..Can you give me you user id?